# Export Devexpress XtraPivotGrid with theme to pdf using Itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, devexpress, itext

I am using **DevExpress ASPXPivotGrid** control for my `ASP.NET` site.I am also using DevExpress **ASPXPivotGridExporter** control to ASPXPivotGrid to **pdf**. The problem I am having is that ASPXPivotGridExporter cannot export **themes** and **right to left languages**. Exported output always come out with default formating and just left to right languages. I would like to know if its possible to export pivot grid with theme and with `rtl languages` ? If not is there work around it with `ITextSharp`?
this what I tried so far

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=TestPage.pdf")
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
ASPXPivotGrid1.RenderControl(hw)
Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
pdfDoc.Open()
htmlparser.Parse(sr)
Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream
Chart1.SaveImage(memoryStream, ChartImageFormat.Png)
Dim img As Image = Image.GetInstance(memoryStream.GetBuffer())
img.ScalePercent(75.0F)
pdfDoc.Add(img)
End Using
pdfDoc.Close()
Response.Write(pdfDoc)
Response.[End]()
```

Comment: I see that you are using `HTMLWorker`. That has been deprecated in favor of `XMLWorker`. Which version of ITextSharp are you using anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `aspxpivotgridexporter` doesn't support right to left languages. but finally i was able to find a work around by exporting pivot grid to html using pivot grid exporter then I can add the needed styles to the resulting html file and adding the direction to the text wither `rtl or ltr`